# Plotting an intersection in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I plot an intersection of two surfaces in Matlab?

I mean this in the sense, that any line in 3D is an intersection - it can be defined by two equations in a system. How do I plot a system of two equations (one implicit, one explicit) in Matlab?

Pardon the confusion, let me explain more clearly what I meant:
I've two equations - that of an ellipsoid and that of a plane, their intersection would give an ellipse (a curved line in three dimensions), I want to plot that line, preferably using Matlab's symbolics.

Ellispoid equation:

$x^2/a + y^2/a +z^2/b = 1$

Plane equation:

$x_0*x/a + y_0*y/a + z_0*z/b = 1$

Comment: try [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2814-showing-intersection-line-between-several-surfaces-in-a-3d-plot)

Comment: Can you specify more clearly how these surfaces are defined?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the question to be more clear